# SwiftUI re-orderable non full screen list

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

The intended goal is a View that expands in height to show all its elements (no scrolling), that can allow its elements to be drag and dropped to re ordered them. I believe a SwiftUI list will support this drag and drop behaviour however when placed in a VStack with other elements, it limits it's height to be the size of one element. I presume these List views aren't intended to be used within another view?

```
List {
   ForEach(viewModel.sections, id: \.self) { section in
      HStack {
         Text(section.localisedString)
         Spacer()
         Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3")
            .foregroundColor(ColourPalette.bodyText)
            .smallIcon()
      }
      .background(ColourPalette.background)
      .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
   }
   .background(ColourPalette.background)
}
.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
.background(ColourPalette.background)
```

I would also like to hide the separators however this appears to be an ongoing struggling with SwiftUI but even the `SideBarListStyle()` doesn't work for me.

Does it make more sense to use a `VStack()` and if so how easily can the reorder on drag drop and classic list side bar items be implemented?

Comment: Maybe using `Section` inside your `List` with a `header` or `footer` will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You have tow options :

## 1) Using `List`

For placing the `VStack` with your `List` , use `Section` with `header` / `footer`, like that it will scroll with the list

```
List {
    Section(header: Text("Your header here")) {
        ForEach(viewModel.sections, id: \.self) { section in
            HStack {
                Text(section.localisedString)
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3")
                    .foregroundColor(ColourPalette.bodyText)
                    .smallIcon()
            }
            .background(ColourPalette.background)
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
        }
        .background(ColourPalette.background)
    }
}
```

And for removidng the separator (**IOS 13 support**):

Adding `UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = .clear` anywhere in your code before the `List` appears should work. While this solution removes the separators, note that all `List` instances will be bound to this style as there’s no official way currently to only remove separators of specific instances. You may be able to run this code in `onAppear` and undo it in `onDisappear` to keep styles different.

## 2) Use VStack / LazyVStack

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will give it ago soon! Cheers :)